# how to dismiss AlertDialog with radio buttons in android sdk

Tags: android

i have created a alertdialog with two radio buttons in it.when user select an option i need to dismiss the alertdialog but i am not been able to dismiss it.

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"First Option", "Second Option"};

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
 builder.setTitle("Choose an option"); 
 builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
       public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       } 
 });
 final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

Can someone help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try this..

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"First Option", "Second Option"};

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
 builder.setTitle("Choose an option"); 
 builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
   public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   } 
});
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: @Rishi if you find this is work then upvote and right this answer so may help to other also.

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
dialog.cancel();


final CharSequence[] items = {"First Option", "Second Option"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose an option"); 
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
              public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item],  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                   dialog.cancel();
              } 
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

in `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isChecked())
{
  dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setSingleChoiceItems` has Dialog `instance` in it.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // here is the instance
          countryBtn.setHint(countryList.get(which));
          dialog.cancel();
         }
```

Use that `instance` to dismiss it either by.

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

OR

```
dialog.cancel();
```